# AutoHotkey - Send on UP disabls Down for the specified key.

Tags: windows, autohotkey

A simple example,

```
a Up::Send b
return
```

Pressing a DOWN does not produce an "a", it produces nothing.

I would like to have "a" in a DOWN state until it is released, at which point a single "b" is sent.

Am I misunderstanding how the Up parameter works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
~a Up::send, b
```

or this:

```
~a::
Keywait, a 
Send, b 
return
```

or:

```
~a::
While (GetkeyState("a", "p"))
    Continue
Send, b
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to my question.

```
~a::Send a
a Up::Send b
```

solves the problem.